# Understanding "the trait X cannot be made into an object" for `&mut Box<Self>` parameter

Tags: rust

I've got this code snippet ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d9c897a53513ecd86e7ecaf241a399cd)):

```rust
struct TeddyBear {
    fluffiness: u8,
}

trait Scruffy {
    fn scruff_up(self: &mut Box<Self>) -> Box<dyn Scruffy>;
}

impl Scruffy for TeddyBear {
    fn scruff_up(self: &mut Box<Self>) -> Box<dyn Scruffy> {
        // do something about the TeddyBear's fluffiness
    }
}
```

It doesn't compile. The error is:

> the trait `Scruffy` cannot be made into an object

, along with the hint:

> because method `scruff_up's` `self` parameter cannot be dispatched on.

I checked the "[E0038](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error-index.html#E0038)" error description, but I haven't been able to figure out which category my error falls into.

I also read the "[object-safety](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/traits.html#object-safety)" entry in "The Rust Reference", and I believe this matches the "All associated functions must either be dispatchable from a trait object", but I'm not sure, partly because I'm not sure what "receiver" means in that context.

Can you please clarify for me what's the problem with this code and why it doesn't work?

Comment: Looks like this might potentially be an oversight in the compiler -- the double indirection caused by taking a mutable reference to a `Box` may not have been covered in the implemented safe trait object receivers list. In any case, why do you need the double indirection of a `&mut Box<Self>` instead of just `&mut self` or `Box<Self>`?

Comment: I'm still wrapping my head around pointers and indirection. I want to mutate the `fluffiness`. As far as I recall `Box<Self>` isn't mutable - and that's the reason I added the `&mut` prefix to it. The `&mut self` option might work in this scenario, but I was curious about the error when using a Box<Self> parameter. I actually know that I could use `fn scruff_up(mut self: Box<Self>) -> Box<dyn Scruffy>`, but the question is more about why the presented approach doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A receiver is the `self` (`&self`, `&mut self`, `self: &mut Box<Self>` and so on).

Note that the list you cited from the reference lists both `Box<Self>` and `&mut Self`, but does not list `&mut Box<Self>` nor it says that combinations of these types are allowed.

This is, indeed, forbidden. As for the why, it is a little more complex.

In order for a type to be a valid receiver, it needs to hold the following condition:

Given any type `Self` that implements `Trait` and the receiver type `Receiver`, the receiver type should implement [`DispatchFromDyn<dyn Trait>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/trait.DispatchFromDyn.html) for itself with all `Self` occurrences of `Self` replaced with `dyn Trait`.

For instance:

`&self` (has the type `&Self`) has to implement `DispatchFromDyn<&dyn Trait>`, [which it does](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/trait.DispatchFromDyn.html#impl-DispatchFromDyn%3C%26%27a%20U%3E).

`Box<Self>` has to implement `DispatchFromDyn<Box<dyn Trait>>`, [which it does](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/trait.DispatchFromDyn.html#impl-DispatchFromDyn%3CBox%3CU%2C%20Global%3E%3E).

But in order for `&mut Box<Self>` to be an object-safe receiver, it would need to impl `DispatchFromDyn<&mut Box<dyn Trait>>`. What you want is kind of blanket implementation `DispatchFromDyn<&mut T> for &mut U where U: DispatchFromDyn<T>`.

This impl will **never** exist. Because it is unsound (even ignoring coherence problems).

[As explained in the code in rustc that calculates this](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/d13e8dd41d44a73664943169d5b7fe39b22c449f/compiler/rustc_trait_selection/src/traits/object_safety.rs#L609-L615):

> The only case where the receiver is not dispatchable, but is still a valid receiver type (just not object-safe), is when there is more than one level of pointer indirection. E.g., `self: &&Self`, `self: &Rc<Self>`, `self: Box<Box<Self>>`. In these cases, there is no way, or at least no inexpensive way, to coerce the receiver from the version where `Self = dyn Trait` to the version where `Self = T`, where `T` is the unknown erased type contained by the trait object, because the object that needs to be coerced is behind a pointer.

The problem is inherent to how Rust handles `dyn Trait`.

`dyn Trait` is a fat pointer: it is actually *two* words sized. One is a pointer to the data, and the other is a pointer to the vtable.

When you call a method on `dyn Trait`, the compiler looks up in the vtable, find the method for the *concrete* type (which is unknown at compilation time, but known at runtime), and calls it.

This all may be very abstract without an example:

```rust
trait Trait {
    fn foo(&self);
}

impl Trait for () {
    fn foo(&self) {}
}

fn call_foo(v: &dyn Trait) {
    v.foo();
}

fn create_dyn_trait(v: &impl Trait) {
    let v: &dyn Trait = v;
    call_foo(v);
}
```

The compiler generates code like:

```rust
trait Trait {
    fn foo(&self);
}

impl Trait for () {
    fn foo(&self) {}
}

struct TraitVTable {
    foo: fn(*const ()),
}
static TRAIT_FOR_UNIT_VTABLE: TraitVTable = TraitVTable {
    foo: unsafe { std::mem::transmute(<() as Trait>::foo) },
};

type DynTraitRef = (*const (), &'static TraitVTable);
impl Trait for dyn Trait {
    fn foo(self: DynTraitRef) {
        (self.1.foo)(self.0)
    }
}

fn call_foo(v: DynTraitRef) {
    v.foo();
}

fn create_dyn_trait(v: &impl Trait) {
    let v: DynTraitRef = (v as *const (), &TRAIT_FOR_UNIT_VTABLE);
    call_foo(v);
}
```

Now suppose that the pointer to the value is behind an indirection. I'll use `Box<&self>` because it's simple but demonstrates the concept best, but the concept applies to `&mut Box<Self>` too: they have the same layout. How will we write `foo()` for `impl Trait for dyn Trait`?

```rust
trait Trait {
    fn foo(self: Box<&Self>);
}

impl Trait for () {
    fn foo(self: Box<&Self>) {}
}

struct TraitVTable {
    foo: fn(Box<*const ()>),
}
static TRAIT_FOR_UNIT_VTABLE: TraitVTable = TraitVTable {
    foo: unsafe { std::mem::transmute(<() as Trait>::foo) },
};

type DynTraitRef = (*const (), &'static TraitVTable);
impl Trait for dyn Trait {
    fn foo(self: Box<DynTraitRef>) {
        let concrete_foo: fn(Box<*const ()>) = self.1.foo;
        let data: *const () = self.0;
        concrete_foo(data) // We need to wrap `data` in `Box`! Error.
    }
}
```

You may think "then the compiler should just insert a call to `Box::new()`!" But besides `Box` not being the only one here (what with `Rc`, for example?) and we will need some trait to abstract over this behavior, **Rust never performs any hard work implicitly**. This is a design choice, and an important one (as opposed to e.g. C++, where an innocent-looking statement like `auto v1 = v;` can allocate and copy 10GB by a copy constructor). Converting a type to `dyn Trait` and back is done implicitly: the first one by a coercion, the second one when you call a method of the trait. Thus, the only thing that Rust does for that is attaching a VTable pointer in the first case, or discarding it in the second case. Even allowing only references (`&&&Self`, no need to call a method, just take the address of a temporary) exceeds that. And it can have severe implications in unexpected places, e.g. register allocation.

So, what to do? You can take `&mut self` or `self: Box<Self>`. Which one to choose depends on whether you need ownership (use `Box`) or not (use a reference). And anyway, `&mut Box<Self>` is not so useful (its only advantage over `&mut T` is that you can replace *the box* and not just *its contents*, but when you do that that's usually a mistake).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is when you pass it in as a reference, because the inner type may not be well-sized (e.g. a trait object, like if you passed in a `Box<Fluffy>`) the compiler doesn't have enough information to figure out how to call methods on it.  If you restrict it to sized objects (like your `TeddyBear`) it should compile

```
trait Scruffy {
    fn scruff_up(self: &mut Box<Self>) -> Box<dyn Scruffy> where Self: Sized;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I have to admit that I don't understand the explanation, likely because I've yet to read the last 3 chapters of The Rust Programming Language book. I know that there's a section there about smart pointers and size. I'll get back to this later if I still have questions.